# Does Fortran 77 contain intrinsic ALL function

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I'm trying to check if all elements of a logical array are false without iterating through it.  I cannot find in the `ALL()` function in the Compaq Visual Fortran 6.6 manual.  Is there some other intrinsic way of doing this, or is `ALL()` supported by Fortran 77?

Here's what I've tried.  It compiles, but I'm worried that it will do something wrong since it's not in the manual:

```
IF(ALL(JLOGICALS .EQV. .FALSE.)) THEN
    !... 
END IF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ALL` statement was added in the Fortran 90 Standard, so strictly speaking, it is not available for a pure FORTRAN 77 compiler.

However, most compilers support the statement, and with Fortran you can mix the Standards. Your code should run fine...

[Here](https://www.xlsoft.com/jp/products/intel/cvf/docs/vf-html_e/azsumm/rfarrtab.htm) is a list of intrinsics that are supported by Compaq Visual Fortran 6.6. `ALL` is among them.

Comment: See, for example, [Fortran Forum Volume 33 Issue 2, pp 8-20](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2647342.2647343).